# WebSphere Application Server local repository admin not able to login

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

WAS is configured to use an Active Directory to authenticate, but the default admin account was left on the local file repository.  When the AD connection is working we are able to login to the admin console using the default admin account, but when AD is down we are not able to use the default admin account to login.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link [Unable to authenticate when a repository is down](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/UnableToAuthenticateWhenRepositoryIsDown.html). You didnt write which version you are running, but by default if one of the federated repos is down you will not be able to log in.
You can use [updateIdMgrRealm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rxml_atidmgrrealmconfig.html#rxml_atidmgrrealmconfig__cmd12) wsadmin command to set the `–allowOperationIfReposDown` parameter to `true`. This will allow you to log in with the user from working repository.